# (Very) old InstallShield-installed application won't uninstall: "ISU corrupted"

Tags: installshield

On a Windows 10 x64 machine, I installed some ancient HP software for an equally-ancient USB scanner. The attempt was a bust (software couldn't find the hardware), and I ended up setting up a Windows 7 x86 machine to use the hardware.

My problem now is that I can't uninstall the software:

[image: The log file ... is not valid or corrupted. Uninstallation will not continue.]

I'm fine with doing a manual search-and-destroy on files, services, registry entries, etc. but how can I find out what those should be so I can find them easily?

Comment: I would reinstall the software. It appears the uninstall executable is missing, but in all likelihood, you can simply delete the folder.

Comment: It's added other stuff for startup things and hardware detection, so I'd like to properly clean it up if I can.

Comment: Can you clarify. Most installers just dump everything in a single folder. Very few applications actually use the registry

Comment: Try Revo Uninstaller and see if that removes the software.

Comment: That did the trick. As I suspected, the registry was littered with stuff. Thanks!

@Ramhound - this is a software application that works with specific hardware. It installs several background applications, a driver, and adds a bunch of stuff to the registry. In the late 90s, applications frequently wrote to the registry a bunch.

Comment: @ClairelyClaire - I learned the majority of what I know in the 90s installers were messy but most never actually wrote any substantial to the registry.